# INNER JOIN between 2 tables vs WHERE on one table performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Suppose I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `doctors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clinic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `clinics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The next queries returns the same data but for large tables wich is better for performance?

1. Query with INNER JOIN

   SELECT `doctors`.*
     FROM `doctors`
    INNER JOIN `clinics`
       ON `clinics`.`id` = `doctors`.`clinic_id`
    WHERE `clinics`.`id` = 1;
2. Query only with WHERE

   SELECT `doctors`.*
     FROM `doctors`
    WHERE `doctors`.`clinic_id` = 1;

Comment: You can always try this yourself by EXPLAIN.  If the plan of the first version contains more rows than that of the second one, it will surely be slower.  (Which is my tip anyway.)  Anyway, why would you use the first version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query. But why are you comparing them?

They may return the same data but they are answering two different questions. The first retrieves all records from `doctors` where a record exists in `clinic` with `id=1`. The second retrieves all records from doctors with `clinic_id=1` regardless of whether a record exists in `clinic`.

In the absence of a foreign key constraint between the two tables, the queries are not comparable.

Comment: If there is a foreign key, the 2 queries will be equivalent but MySQL's optimizer cannot use that. MariaDB's optimizer though has [Table elimination](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/table-elimination/) which I think does exactly that.